# What is the purpose of ActionsObservable in redux-observable

Tags: redux-observable

I don't quite understand what is the purpose of [ActionsObservable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/src/ActionsObservable.js). There's nothing about it in the documentation but I see it being used here and there [in examples](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html).

Why not just use:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

or

```
import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Once I started writing test I came across a situation where an epic has been calling:

`action$.ofType(CREATE_PAYMENT_METHOD))`

and because a "regular" Observable doesn't have `ofType` in prototype chain it was throwing an error when I was stubbing actions:

```
const action$ = of({
  type: types.CREATE_PAYMENT,
});

const response = await epics.createPayment(action$, store, fetch)
  .pipe(toArray()).toPromise();
```

> action$.ofType is not a function

It worked when I used:

```
const action$ = ActionsObservable.of({
  type: types.CREATE_PAYMENT,
});
```